MikroORM relation from an entity to a virtual entity
I have an entity StockItem, this contains multiple @ManyToOne relations. There is a view called StockItemStatus that summarises the many to one relations to a single value (e.g. list of stock changes to the current stock level).
However, in MikroORM I am unable to relate the view to the entity.
@Entity()
export class StockItem {
    @PrimaryKey()
    id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => StockItemStatus, status => status.stockItem, { eager: true })
    status: Ref<StockItemStatus>;

    ...
}

@Entity({ expression: 'select * from stock_item_status' })
export class StockItemStatus {
    @OneToOne(() => StockItem, {
        joinColumn: 'stock_item_id', // StockItemStatus.stockItemId
        inverseJoinColumn: 'id' // StockItem.Id,
    })
    stockItem: Ref<StockItem>;

    ...
}

This works for all operations apart from create where I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match').
I need to do this as otherwise I have ~10 @Formula on the entity and it takes a while to load.
I am using NestJS and GraphQL and am open to otherwise to achieve this.
I also need to able to query the related properties, so using GQL field resolvers is not the solution. MikroORM needs to be aware of the relation.

I managed to do it by having stock item status as a virtual entity:
@Entity({ expression: 'select * from stock_item_status' })
export class StockItemWithStatus {
    @Property()
    stockItemId: number;
    ...
}

Then I can easily fetch it via em.findOneOrFile(StockItemWithStatus, { stockItemId: { stockItem.id }).
Then the only other issue was filtering. But that can done via raw sql:
[raw(`(s1.id in (select stock_item_id from stock_level_current slc where slc.current_level ${hasStock ? '>' : '<='} 0))`)]: []

The only issue I can see is if the stock item table is not called s1.

When using QueryBuilder, you can define the alias explicitly to avoid relying on MikroORM's default behavior.
    .createQueryBuilder(StockItem, 's1') // Explicitly set alias
    .select('*')
    .where(
        raw(
            `(s1.id in (select stock_item_id from stock_level_current slc where slc.current_level ${hasStock ? '>' : '<='} 0))`
        )
    )
    .getResultList();```

Views are not meant to be used in CRUD operations directly because they are read-only by nature, so you can't insert or update records in the view.You can tell MikroORM that the StockItemStatus is a read-only entity. This way, MikroORM will understand that the StockItemStatus view is only for querying purposes and will not attempt to persist changes to it:
@Entity({ expression: 'select * from stock_item_status', readOnly: true })
export class StockItemStatus {
    @PrimaryKey()
    id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => StockItem, stockItem => stockItem.status)
    stockItem: Ref<StockItem>;
}

If StockItemStatus is not meant to be persisted, you can define it as a virtual property in StockItem. This allows MikroORM to understand the relation but without trying to persist it.It makes it as a virtual property that can be populated with a custom query:
@Entity()
export class StockItem {
    @PrimaryKey()
    id: number;

    @Property({ persist: false })
    status: StockItemStatus;

    async loadStatus(): Promise<void> {
        this.status = await this.entityManager.findOne(StockItemStatus, { stockItem: this });
    }
}

Since you're using GraphQL, you could as well consider using a custom resolver to handle fetching the StockItemStatus based on the StockItem. This way, MikroORM doesn't need to manage the relation directly, but your application can still return the status efficiently:
@Resolver(() => StockItem)
export class StockItemResolver {
    constructor(private readonly stockItemService: StockItemService) {}

    @FieldResolver(() => StockItemStatus)
    async status(@Root() stockItem: StockItem) {
        return this.stockItemService.getStatus(stockItem.id); // Custom logic to fetch the status
    }
}


Thank you for your response.
I have tried all of those methods and they still keep causing the same issue.
Is there any way I can just join my stock_item_status table to the entity?
I managed to get it working via @Formula on each property and proxying the view that view but when I filter by those properties it takes an extremely long time
